# Can you use GetLegendGraphic for a ArcGIS Server 9.3 WMS?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

The following request should return a legend graphic for a particular layer:

http://myserver/arcgis/services/default/MapServer/WMSServer?Service=WMS&Request=GetLegendGraphic&Version=1.1.1&Layer=3&FORMAT=image/png

However instead I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
  <ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">
Can't parse XML request.
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

The GetCapabilities request for the service for the layer contains the following:

```
<Style>
<Name>default</Name>
<Title>Layer Name</Title>
<LegendURL width="100" height="62">
<Format>image/png</Format>
<OnlineResource xlink:href="http://server/arcgisoutput/wms/default1.png" xlink:type="simple"/>
</LegendURL>
</Style>
```

The OnlineResource href is a valid PNG file that is accessible externally.

It seems [others](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=1696&t=274808) have had issues, and recommend using [external capabilities files](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotNet/index.htm#wms_external_cap_files.htm), but when the legend already has a valid image file is this necessary? Has anyone successfully configured a WMS to support the GetLegendGraphic request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears for ArcGIS Server 9.x the GetLegendGraphic operation was [never implemented](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/wms_scope_compat_matrix.htm). Apparently this operation is an optional implementation and is not a part of the "basic WMS" standard.

From the [ESRI docs](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/wms_service.htm):

> "it is not necessary for a WMS service
>   to support all the operations. But one
>   must support at least GetCapabilities
>   and GetMap operations to be a "Basic
>   WMS"

The good news however is that in ArcGIS Server 10 this functionality has [now been added](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/WMS_services/005300000044000000/).